# 画像の上下に空欄出てしまいます。それを消したいです

Tags: css

ウェブページでどうしても空白ができてしまい困っています。
pタグで囲みたいのですが、pタグを使うとどうしても上下に空白ができてしまいます。
この空白を消したいです。
どうしたらよいのでしょうか？

[image: header-boxの画像です]
[image: 青い海の画像と下の同じく海の画像との間に空白ができてしまいます。]

```
<body>
   <div id="pc-wrapper">
      <div id="pc-header-box">
         <p><img src="aaa"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="pc-logo-box">
         <img src="logo">
      </div>
      <div id="pc-page-box1">
         <p><img src="bbb"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="pc-page-box2">
         <p><img src="bbb"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="pc-page-box3">
         <p><img src="ccc"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="pc-page-box4">
         <p><img src="ddd"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="pc-page-box5">
         <p><img src="eee"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="pc-page-box6">
         <p><img src="fff"></p>
      </div>
   </div>
<body>
```

css

```
#pc-wrapper
{
  display:block;
  width:1300px;
  height:1800px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#pc-header-box
{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:1300px;
  height:800px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#pc-logo-box
{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:1300px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#30F;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#pc-logo-box img
{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#pc-page-box1
{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background-color:#69C;
  width:650px;
  height:430px;
}

#pc-page-box1 p
{
  display:block;
  background-color:#F99;
}
```

Comment: Normalized CSS等って使用していますか？ 例：http://jsfiddle.net/s7mrrbqt/

Answer (score 3):

`<p>` タグには多くのブラウザで上下マージンが設定されていますから、それを上書きすればいいと思います。

（追記）インライン要素である `<img>` はデフォルトで `vertical-align: baseline` になっているため、それでも若干の隙間が空くようでした。これを避けるには `vertical-align: bottom` で上書きするか、 `display: block` とするのがよいでしょう。

参考 [（アクセシビリティも考えて）画像の下にできる余白をなくす | 誠](http://daisukenagai.com/blog/4.html)

上記2点を合わせて、こんな感じでいがかでしょうか。

```
#pc-wrapper p
{
  margin: 0;
}
#pc-wrapper img
{
  display: block;
  /* imgを横にも並べたい時など、 vertical-align: bottom でもOK */
}
```

サンプル

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  /* display: block; */
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<p><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" /><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" /></p>
<p><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" /></p>
```

余談ですが、 `<div>` や `<p>` は元々ブロック要素ですから、どこかで上書きされていない限り `display: block` は不要ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 私もこれでいいと思い、試したのですが、Google Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m (Windows)では、どうにも`<p>`のcomputed styleで`height`に画像の縦幅+4pxが設定されて余白が見えてしまいます。それぞれの`<p>`に画像の縦幅と同じ`height`を指定すると余白がなくなるので、そうしなければならないのかな…と調べているところであります。

Comment: @KIDtheEuforia ご指摘ありがとうございます、インライン要素であることを忘れていました。回答を修正したのでよろしければご確認くださいませ。

Comment: 確認いたしました。先ほどと同環境で確認し、まったく余白がなくなっておりました！修正ありがとうございます。そして、勉強になりました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: すばらしい！！一発回答です。まったく問題なく動きました！

Comment: @webman さん。 解決したようですので、この解答にチェックを付けていただけると回答された方の励みにもなりますし、質問者にも評価点がつきます。ぜひよろしくお願いします。